# With tinyMCE how to make a rich-text editor coexist with another textarea?

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor

After reading a few examples of tinyMCE, the project is like changing every available textarea into a rich-text editor. I never find it init with an element id or selector by any kind. So can I make an ordinary textarea co-exist with a tinyMCE rich-text editor?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas"
});
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

You can either set the **mode** to "**exact**" and specify the ID's of the textarea(s) you want converted to TinyMCE instances using the [elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aelements) config item.

Alternatively you can set the **mode** to "**specific_textareas**" and specify the CSS class you want to assign to the appropriate textareas that are to be converted to TinyMCE instances using the [editor_selector](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_selector) config item.

Comment: Hi, Brett, Thanks a lot! I'm giving that a try

Comment: Siva, this question is in relation to how to load TinyMCE for a specific TextArea. Check out the TinyMCE Config on how to set a specific Width, or set your TextArea width.